# "reverse-engineering" a certain pdf

Tags: formatting, pdf, margins

I am trying to figure out how to create a latex amble that would lead to a PDF similar to the following: http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.4413

I am talking about margins, font size (of various headers, etc.), location of the title, authors, etc.

Anyone has an idea how to "reverse-engineer" the PDF in this specific case?

Comment: In that particular case you can download the LaTeX source file: [link to download](http://arxiv.org/format/0811.4413v5). Most of the time journals or conferences (books too) provide templates that you can download from their homepages.